# Why is my smoke alarm chirping even with fresh batteries?

Tags: smoke-detectors, alarm, smoke

One of our smoke alarms started doing a short chirp every couple of hours. I assumed it was due to a low battery, so I replaced it. Didn’t help still beeping every couple hours.

I then unplugged it from the wall, took the battery out and held the test button down. Then replaced the battery and plugged it back in, still chirping every couple hours.

I then replaced the entire smoke alarm, still chirping.

THEN replaced every battery in every smoke detector in my house and still chirping every couple of hours.

Any idea what else I can try?! It’s driving me nuts

Comment: Are they interconnected? Is the known chirpy one just a smoke or is it also CO?

Comment: Oh, and are they hardwired for main power (with a battery backup)?

Comment: They are hardwired with battery backup. It is just a smoke no CO

Comment: Can you test if the "bad" one is actually getting power? If you don't have tools to test that, maybe swap it with another hardwired one in your house?

Comment: Interesting. I don’t have anything to test it but I’m not opposed to getting something to test with. What would I use?

Comment: Best thing is to go to your electrical panel and flip all the breakers off and on once. For this (and many other electrical things), get a non-contact voltage tester. They’re in a pen format and super handy.

Comment: Okay I’m at a loss. I just unplugged the beeping detector, took the battery out and cleared it by holding test. And now another one somewhere in the house is beeping. Wtf

Comment: Usually a low battery warning is every few minutes, not a couple of hours.  What is the age of the smoke detectors?

Comment: I actually just timed it. It was only about 14 minutes. The original culprit is brand new I bought it yesterday to replace the old one

Comment: Here is the owners manual for your detectors.  The chirping behavior you describe is not documented but that is often the case.  Interconnected detectors can misbehave in all sorts of ways that might as well be ghosts in your walls.
https://digitalassets.resideo.com/damroot/Original/10002/M08-179722.pdf

Comment: one of the smoke alarms may have expired ... check the expiry dates

Answer (score 1):

Take all of the batteries out and disconnect any hardwired smoke detectors. Hold the test button to discharge them. Wait 10 minutes. If you hear any beeps after that, you missed at least one. Go find it.

Or something else is beeping: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kdnnnvo7puk

Once you are done, make sure to put the batteries back in!

Comment: I appreciate it but I already did that. One singular detector beeping even after being replaced.

Comment: What the make and model number of that smoke detector?

Comment: First Alert SMI100-AC

Comment: Could also be [one of these](https://amzn.to/47b9MEV)

Comment: It’s definitely not that. I can stand under the smoke detector and hear it beep.

Comment: Okay I’m at a loss. I just unplugged the beeping detector, took the battery out and cleared it by holding test. And now another one somewhere in the house is beeping. Wtf

Comment: @JohnRyan yes that is common for interconnected detectors.  One detector may chirp to indicate another one is faulty.

Comment: Unplug one at a time until the chirping stops?